# Why does the capacitor need to be small in RC filter circuits?

Tags: capacitor, filter, low-pass, passive-filter, bypass-capacitor

[image]

Hi there, in this example, it mentions that "One should choose R2 to be as close to 100kohm (to make the C2 small)".

My question is: what are the reasons for C2 to be small? Other than the fact that R2 needs to be large enough so that there's no loading effect.

Does it have anything to do with ESL and/or ESR?

Answer (score 6):

Basically, lower valued capacitors can use dielectric materials that have better performance. Less variability due to temperature and bias voltage. Less variability over time. Higher working voltage ratings.

The best materials generally only deliver capacitance values up to 100 nF or so at reasonable prices.

Here, we're talking about \$RC=1\ {\rm s}\$, so if R is 100 kohms, then C will be 10 uF. In this range, keeping the capacitor value lower (i.e. 10 uF instead of 22 or 100 uF) will allow you to keep the part physically smaller (which is good if you need to fit it on a board with a bunch of other stuff), and/or allow you to have a slightly better working voltage rating.

Comment: Upon seeing "best materials generally" followed by "100 nF" made me think of PTFE in that size. I think I'd like to see one. ;)

Comment: @jonk, maybe I should have said the materials that are at least kind of okay for filter applications.

Comment: That makes me chuckle. :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Here the lower cutoff frequency is 160Hz. So the product of RC has to be 1x10^-3. If R is smaller than 100kohm, C will have to be larger than 10nF.

Comment: @justamapler, so you're stuck using "not-so-great" materials in your capacitor. That means the cut-off frequency will move around quite a bit depending on temperature, etc. If you increase R to 1 megohm you could maybe parallel several 100 nF capacitors (or pay a bunch for a 1 uF cap)  in "sorta okay" material (C0G ceramic). Increasing R to 10 megohms or higher leads to other risks (dirt on your board starts to act like another resistor in parallel with the intentional one), but is also possible.

Comment: @jonk, by the way, https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0085/1863/1479/files/electrocube-463d-polytetrafluoroethylene-ptfe-teflon-metallized-high-temp-cap-093015.pdf (parts up to 1.0 uF)

Comment: @ThePhoton Wow. Now all I need to do is find a supplier who can ship one. Hehe.

Answer (score 1):

Smaller caps may be necessary for higher frequency or higher impedance or high voltage, but not always.  Here, the application is not that high f, (as in RF) but the load impedance was stated to be high at 1 Meg.  This makes it convenient to use small ceramic caps, which are inexpensive with a large R-value, where the breakpoint is defined by  ω=1/RC.

Usually one designs a filter to not change by the load so a casual solution might only be 10% of the load, others might choose 1% of the load.  Other applications like RF and speaker crossovers need special components for high current or 50 Ohm impedance, but not here.

Every cap has an internal Effective Series Resistance, ESR, often overlooked,  (you must when not to overlook, ) so that each similar type has a predictable ESR*C=Tau or dissipation factor at 120Hz.

Its effective series inductance ESL may be important above 1 MHz , if they are large parts, but less likely, if they are small. The datasheet may define it as a self or series resonant frequency SRF.

There may be a dozen different reasons for selecting any capacitor.

For-example; Cost, availability, tolerance at room temp, sensitivity to temperature, with high stability such as NP0 ceramic or plastic metal film types or high ripple current (low ESR e-caps) or it just happens to be what's on hand.  In professional or commercial R&D environments, each part, vendor and family must be approved by some Component , Design or Quality Engineer and added to an inhouse approved part database.

Using the https://www.Falstad.com/afilter site you can design/choose, build & verify your passive/active filter designs. See menu for simple details. Parts are ideal, so add ESR,DCR if needed.

Using mouse or keyboard, R place R, drag ends to stretch or move, C for cap, G for gnd , space bar for move parts, mouse pick + Ctrl= stretch end of part. etc. etc.

[image]

AS in Question; HPF + LPF 160 to 8000 Hz at -3dB points.

Here I used LPF with 100k as suggested then chose 100pF and verified -3dB was 16kHz , so I doubled C to get 8kHz.  However for RF they use LC filters with lower impedance. Sliders on right scale X & Y .

[Here I didn't follow the impedance rules](https://www.falstad.com/afilter/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%205%2050%205%2050%0A%25%200%20256649.19037183083%0Ac%20608%20432%20688%20432%200%200.00001%200%0Ar%20688%20432%20688%20512%200%20100%0AO%20816%20432%20864%20432%200%0Ag%20688%20512%20688%20528%200%0A170%20560%20432%20528%20432%203%2020%201000%205%200.1%0Ar%20608%20432%20560%20432%200%2050%0Ar%20688%20432%20752%20432%200%201000%0Ac%20752%20432%20752%20512%200%202e-8%200%0Aw%20688%20512%20752%20512%200%0Aw%20752%20512%20816%20512%200%0Aw%20752%20432%20816%20432%200%0Ar%20816%20512%20816%20432%200%201000000%0As%20560%20400%20608%20400%200%200%20false%0Aw%20560%20432%20560%20400%200%0Aw%20608%20432%20608%20400%200%0Ao%204%2016%200%2034%205%200.00009765625%200%20-1%20in%0Ao%202%2016%200%2034%202.5%200.00009765625%201%20-1%20out%0A), ended up with big electr. caps and then added a switch to show effect of a real sig. gen with 50 Ohm Impedance. Yet ended up with same spectral shape.  Now you have to worry about DC current if any in the e-cap and are using slightly more expensive caps.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! Very detailed and helpful information. By "Usually one designs a filter to not change by the load so a casual solution might only be 10% of the load, others might choose 1% of the load." do you mean how the answer arrived at R2 = 100k from 1M and R1 = 10k from R2 = 100k? Does Tau (time constant) matter in this filter? Like R2C2 = 1x10^-3, but they are only in series from input impedance and not in series from output impedance perspective?

Comment: Exactly 1st stage 10kohm breakpoint, 2nd stage 100kohm, 3rds stage (load) 1Meg. The  ω=1/RC using the Thevenin equivalent R or approximately just the dominant R is used regardless if series or shunt then interpreted as expected as an impedance divider.  This is a HPF then LPF to make a 1st order BPF. Since Z is high, ESR has no effect.  but if it were higher freq. then ESL might be considered or SRF. https://www.falstad.com/afilter/circuitjs.html?startCircuit=filt-hipass.txt   can analyze the Bode Plot for you. with Options, Phase, built-in  designs etc

Answer (score 1):

---

### DC bias tolerance and temperature benefits smaller capacitors

- COG rated capacitance wont come in larger capacitance
- COG capacitor's capacitance change over time is negligible.
- DC bias is tighter for COG packages making them better suitable products for filtering applications
- higher value capacitors (uF and higher) can vary up-to 50% of the rated capacitor value over the rated DC bias
- the overall area also increases as the capacitor size increases unlike resistors

---

### Comparison of capacitance variation of different packages

[image]

---

### C0G and X7R package availability in Digikey

(no other filters put with respect to supplier, size or voltage rating)

- For COG you have up-to **2uF**
- For X7R you have values up-to **470uF**

---

### from Wiki

- [COG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceramic_capacitor) falls under Class 1
- [X7R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceramic_capacitor) falls under Class 2

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sharing this knowledge! From my understanding, capacitors can be used for filtering AC signals from supply voltage rails and providing instantaneous energy in case of voltage sags. So can we use class 1 caps for filtering AC signals at voltage rails as well seeing it's better in filter circuits?

Comment: @justamapler yes for the vorlage sagpart class 1 will be over design though due to the cost